# Layout align in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am using this code in my xml file

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:gravity="fill_vertical"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_signINlst"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:background="@drawable/draw"
android:text="@string/sign_in" />

 <TextView
android:id="@+id/Left"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
 android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="@string/do_not_have_ac"
 />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_registerlst"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:background="@drawable/draw"

android:text="@string/register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and output is looking fine

[image]

but when i click on register button then automatically changed alignment

[image: changed alignment]

Please help me how i can fix this problem

my all xml file code is

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
    >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:background="@drawable/tab_bar" android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/txt_SEARCH_TITLE"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/search_results" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainlist"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc"
     android:smoothScrollbar="true" 
        android:scrollingCache="false"

      android:dividerHeight="1dp"
             android:divider="#adb8c2"

      >

    </ListView>
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2584288851778590/4570818460"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"
                             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                               android:layout_above="@+id/AboveLinear"
                             ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"/>



    <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/AboveLinear"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="13sp"
    android:text="@string/take_advantage" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signINlst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:text="@string/sign_in" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/do_not_have_ac"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_registerlst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"

        android:text="@string/register" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks In Advance

Any Help Is Appreciated.

Comment: check the button sizes of focus/selected/ buttons of same sizes selector xml in drawable folder. Because in selector xml we will different button sizes & colors to show the button is in focus/selected. Also confirm you are not changing the font size or text in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_SEARCH_TITLE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="search_results"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainlist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#adb8c2"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
</ListView>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/AboveLinear"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2584288851778590/4570818460"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AboveLinear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="take_advantage"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signINlst"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="sign_in" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="do_not_have_ac"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_registerlst"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="register" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay bro But same problem occur

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `android:layout_weight="0.5"` attribute from `Buttons` as below...

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:gravity="fill_vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signINlst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:text="@string/sign_in" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/do_not_have_ac" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_registerlst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:text="@string/register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay bro but not solved problem after removing ndroid:layout_weight="0.5" from buttons

Comment: have you removed that from both buttons?